# Class not found when unmarshalling error. Parcelable with byteArray, byte[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, classnotfoundexception, parcelable

I have an error when using a Parcelable Class.
I'm trying to pass an image as a ByteArray between activities, and eventually to a remote webservice.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...
Class not found when unmarshalling:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Property implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("id")
@NonNull
private final String mId;
protected byte[] mImage;

public byte[] getmImage() {     return mImage;  }

public void setmImage(byte[] image){ mImage = image; }

@SerializedName("generalInformation")
private GeneralInformation mGeneralInformation;

@NonNull
public GeneralInformation getGeneralInformation() {
    return mGeneralInformation;
}

public void setGeneralInformation(@NonNull final GeneralInformation generalInformation) {
    mGeneralInformation = generalInformation;
}
@NonNull
public String getId() {
    return mId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Property) && ((Property) o).mId.equals(mId);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mId.hashCode();
}

public static Property create() {
    final Property model = new Property(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.setGeneralInformation(new GeneralInformation());
    return model;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(@NonNull final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
    if(mImage != null) {
        dest.writeInt(mImage.length);
        dest.writeByteArray(mImage);
    }
    dest.writeString(mId);
    dest.writeParcelable(mGeneralInformation, 0);
}

private Property(@NonNull final String id) {
    mId = id;
}

protected Property(final Parcel in) {
    if(mImage != null)
    {
        mImage = new byte[in.readInt()];
        in.createByteArray();
    }
    mId = in.readString();

    mGeneralInformation = in.readParcelable(GeneralInformation.class.getClassLoader());
    }

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Property> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Property>() {
    public Property createFromParcel(@NonNull final Parcel source) {
        return new Property(source);
    }

    @NonNull
    public Property[] newArray(final int size) {
        return new Property[size];
    }
};
}
```

Now I have a very limited understanding of the problem(s) I have with this class. 
mImage is null when reading the Parcel. (Even when I know for sure that the byteArray is not null when I assign it to the Parcel.) I have tried to initialize mImage in its declaration so it not null but then I have that Class not found when unmarshalling error...

I'm almost sure the problem lies in

```
protected Property(final Parcel in) {
if(mImage != null)
{
    mImage = new byte[in.readInt()];
    in.createByteArray();
}
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

I'm lost for 2 days with this thing :/

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below code for constructor with Parcel object.

```
protected Property(final Parcel in) {
    mImage = new byte[in.readInt()]; 
    in.readByteArray(mImage); // this will read the byte array from Parcel object(in) and store the value in mImage member variable.

    mId = in.readString();

    mGeneralInformation = in.readParcelable(GeneralInformation.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tamal, I don't have the error anymore, but the image is now black, empty. In the meantime I have found a workaround: I pass the Uri in the Parcelable instead of the byteArray. I build the byteArray from the Uri later on.